# How to cancel a Read() call for grpc::ClientReader in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, grpc

I have code that requests a stream of data from a grpc::Server with a grpc::ClientReader. The main loop looks like below, and runs in a seperate task. I need to shutdown task when destructor, but the Read() method is blocking. There doesn't seem to be anything I can do to mcReader to get it to stop blocking. I would rather not use deadline, because data isn't completely periodic, and making it big enough to do antyhign would still block a long time. What should I do?

```
while (mcReader->Read(&dataProductWrapper) && meTasksRunning) 
{
      // Do some work.
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] seems appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So looking around I figured it out. Using the grpc::ClientContext that gets passed into RPC call, you can call grpc::ClientContext::TryCancel() you can cancel from another thread.

Comment: TryCancel is best effort and the call may actually not be cancelled. I am facing this case and so my thread that's waiting on this fails to exit or join at the end. Wondering if you have observed similar issue? The documentation around this isn't great.